# Unicode characters display improperly in KDE and on the console in Arch Linux

Tags: linux, unicode, kde-4

I recently switched from OpenSuSE to Arch Linux. Files with unicode characters in the name used to display fine, but after the switchover I just get mojibake. For example, in my music library Queensrÿche appears as QueensrÃ¿che.

This occurs on the console as well.

I piled on to a [relevant thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134513) in the Arch Linux forums, but haven't gotten an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible that your locale is configured improperly; the most likely reason is that, even though the file names are stored in UTF-8, your terminal (I'm guessing Konsole) still expects a legacy ISO-8859-* encoding.

I don't know the rest, but here are a few steps to ensure the basic configuration is correct.

[This script](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/system/locale-check) may also help.

1. Edit **`/etc/locale.gen`**, ensure that your preferred `.UTF-8` locale (e.g. **`en_US.UTF-8`**) is uncommented.

   (By default, Arch does not enable any locales.)
2. Run **`locale-gen`** to generate the locales, if they haven't been generated yet.

   (Currently generated locales are listed by `locale -a`.)
3. Edit **[`/etc/locale.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Locale.conf)** and add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

   (The `LOCALE=` variable in `/etc/rc.conf` does the same thing, but is, in a way, deprecated in favor of locale.conf.)
4. **Log out completely**, then log in again, in order to refresh the environment variables.
5. Run `env | egrep '^(LANG|LC_)' | sort` to see what locale settings are in your shell's environment.

   Run `tr \\0 \\n < /proc/$PPID/environ | egrep '^(LANG|LC_)' | sort` to see the *terminal's* environment.

   Both commands should return identical output. If not, they *both* must at least have ".UTF-8" in `LANG` values. (".UTF-8" and ".utf8" can be considered identical.) Also, *neither* command should list `LC_ALL`.

Comment: Seems to have done the trick...konsole and dolphin both display the proper characters now! Thanks!

Comment: Github link broken. New [link](https://github.com/grawity/code/blob/master/system/locale-check).

Comment: +1 for this, thanks -- adding LANG to .bash_profile (not .bashrc) did the trick here for getting vim-airline utf-8 symbols displaying in gnome-terminal